# Android : ActionView Collapses on pressing back button

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, back-button

I am using [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) library to get actionbar on pre-Honeycomb versions. I have an activity for which the actionbar menu is inflated from below xml

> **menu.xml**

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">        
    <item android:id="@+id/action_bar_search" 
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_search"
        android:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView" android:title="Search"
        android:actionLayout="@layout/layout_search">        
    </item> 
</menu>
```

Below is the actionLayout

**> layout_search.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <AutoCompleteTextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/autoCompText_action_bar_search"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"    
    android:cursorVisible="true"    
    android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
    android:inputType="text"
    android:textColor="@color/color_action_bar_text"
    android:textCursorDrawable="@android:color/black" 
    android:background="@drawable/textfield_bg_activated_holo_dark"            
    />
```

I have also implemented the OnActionExpandListener to listen to the Expand and Collapse
Events of the menu Item. Below is my implementation of OnActionExpandListener

```
  private OnActionExpandListener searchActionExpandListener = new OnActionExpandListener() {        
            @Override
            public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {              

                /* This is done so that requestFocus() can popup the softkeyboard. 
                 * Else, no softkeyboard is popped up
                 */
                edtTextSearch.post(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        edtTextSearch.requestFocus();
                        mImm = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                        mImm.showSoftInput(edtTextSearch, InputMethodManager.SHOW_IMPLICIT);
                    }
                });
                return true;
            }
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemActionCollapse(MenuItem item) {                
            mImm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(edtTextSearch.getWindowToken(), 0);
            return true;
        }
    };
```

So Now, on pressing the search button on Action bar the actionLayout is displayed and the softkeyboard is popped up as well with focus on it. All works fine till now. But when I press the back key (the hard key on the phone), the action view collapses. All i want to do is hide the soft keyboard(if it is being displayed) on pressing the back key and not collapse the action view. Can anyone please help me out?

Comment: Hi Viren, you should also take a look at my answer for a similar question: [Contextual ActionBar hides when I click on hardware backbutton and the keyboard is out](http://stackoverflow.com/a/23122941/2668136), it might help you.

Comment: Thanks Filo for such an active response. Your link gave me a fresh perspective

Comment: Glad to help! It's weird because I never saw this behaviour on my projects. I'll do some test to know what it's wrong/right in mine. Anyway, I hope this will help you. Good coding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar problem with the `ActionBarSherlock` and a `CollapseActionView`. Your code helped me a lot but I was unable to pop the Soft Keyboard on earlier versions (as 2.+) with a `Runnable()` (don't know why). Just a little trick may avoid you to use this way, see my code below:

```
@Override
public boolean onMenuItemActionExpand(MenuItem item) {              
    // Set the focus
    edtTextSearch.requestFocus();  
    // This force the Soft Keyboard to appear whatever the version used
    mImm.toggleSoftInput(InputMethodManager.SHOW_FORCED,  
                                   InputMethodManager.HIDE_IMPLICIT_ONLY);
    return true;
}
```

This works perferctly in 2.+ and above. Now, for what you ask, I don't see that things on all devices tested. When the `View` expands, the Soft Keyboard appears. Then when I press the back button, the Soft Keyboard dissapears and the `View` doesn't collapse (even in landscape mode). If I'm press it again, here the `View` collapse.
Can you explain more what you want because I don't see properly your action on back button to collapse the `View`?

After some researches, I was thinking that you wanted to keep your `DownDropList` visible with the CollapseActionView, so maybe it will be usefull to look this: [DropDownList of AutoCompleteTextView opened after pressing the Back key?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9722278/how-to-keep-dropdownlist-of-autocompletetextview-opened-after-pressing-the-back). And just in case, I found this: [EditText with soft keyboard and “Back” button](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6570974/edittext-with-soft-keyboard-and-back-button)